# problem reading files in delta lake house - data streaming

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, databricks, spark-streaming, delta-lake

I'm building my first delta lake house in databricks, alone. I need to read files that are in csv format in a bucket in AWS, I can view the folder with my files by doing display(dbutils.fs.ls. However, when doing readStream, it only reads a single file, with all files has the same name, differentiating only the last 4 digits, which are years (2013,2014, 2015).

example: data_from_2013.csv , data_from_2014.csv.

And the only file read, which has exactly the same structure as all the other files, is from 2018.
I believe it is something that I am failing because I need to insert a new column for the year in each file, and the only place that has this data is within the file in column B, line 1, of each file. And after that, I need to delete the first three lines of each file.

```py
path_file = "/mnt/path/path_data/path_data_year/data_from_****.csv"

df_bronze_despesUF_funcao = spark.readStream \
    .format("csv") \
    .schema(schema) \
    .options(header='true', inferSchema='true', 
             delimiter=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', skiprows=3) \
    .load(path_file)
```

Please, anyone can help me?

I've read the Databricks documentation, watched videos, but I can't complete this task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of path_file with `_****.csv`, Just declared path_file as folder

```
path_file = "/mnt/path/path_data/path_data_year/"

df_bronze_despesUF_funcao = spark.readStream
.format("csv")
.schema(schema)
.options(header='true', inferSchema='true', delimiter=';', encoding='iso-8859-1', skiprows=3)
.load(path_file)
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. I managed to read all the files, but can you give me some more help?

I'm reading 12 different files, In these 12 files, each one refers to a year, and I wanted to insert a column with the year that file refers to.

In the case of files, the first line only has "Fiscal year: 2013", and I wanted to make this column a line for each file, but it reads them all as a single year.

I'm doing it this way:

# Extract the year from the file
first_line = spark.read.text(path_files).first()[0]
file_year = re.search(r"\d{4}", first_line).group()

Comment: try to create a new columns within data by using withColumn . example  df.withColumn("Fiscal", functions.date_format(df.col("date"), "YYYY"))